# 'rake routes' modifies vendor/plugins/haml/init.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm getting a strange and annoying bug when I run `rake routes` on a rails project.  Every time it for some reason modifies the file `vendor/plugins/haml/init.rb`.  Here's the diff:

```
-# Load Haml and Sass.
+# Load Haml
```

Using rails version 2.3.4 and my vendored version of Haml is 2.2.23.  I've got a couple of other versions of rails (3.0.7, 3.0.4, 3.0.3) and haml (3.1.2, 3.1.1, 3.0.25), along with haml-rails (0.3.4).  The bug pops up with `rake routes` as well as `rake db:` commands, but not `rake stats`.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, uninstalling the haml gem from my gemset fixed it, such that it just uses the vendored version.  Not sure why the gem version would alter the vendored version, though.  It also works fine if I install the the same gem version as what is in the vendor directory.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version 3.0.22 haml doesn't include sass anymore. You need to install sass gem separately or use haml older than version 3.0.22.

Comment: But why is it editing the version in my vendor directory?  I don't see why rake tasks should cause anything to change there.

Comment: probably it detects new version of gem. look at your logs. do you see deprecation warnings there?

Comment: No, I don't see any deprecation warnings in my development log.